# Schedulable Class not creating new records - Not doing anything

Tags: apex-code, apex

I have a series of accounting objects in Salesforce. The accounts object has a master-detail relationship with a custom Transaction object. This Transaction object should hold all payments and charges made to the account. Charges happen weekly and are based on a field stored in a different object.

I'm trying to write an apex class that, on a weekly basis, will go through and create new Transaction records that reflect the weekly charges. However, the class I've written is running but (as far as I can tell) isn't doing anything.

I'm still new to Object-oriented programming and certainly new to Apex. Any help and references on where to learn more about what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated!

```
global class scheduledWeekly implements Schedulable {

public static String CRON_EXP = '0 50 21 * * ? *';


global static String scheduleIt() {
scheduledWeekly sw = new scheduledWeekly();
return System.schedule('Weekly Billing', CRON_EXP, sw);
}


global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    List <Transaction__c> trans_insert = new List <Transaction__c>();

    Child__c ac = [
        Select Family_Account__c
        From Child__c
        Where Enrolled__c = true];

    Account at = [
        Select Name
            , Weekly_Tuition__c
        From Account
        Where Name = :ac.Family_Account__c
            and Weekly_Tuition__c > 0
    ];

    Account ae = [
        Select Name
            , Extra_Curricular_Tuition_Fee__c
        From Account
        Where Name = :ac.Family_Account__c
            and Extra_Curricular_Tuition_Fee__c > 0
    ];

        for(Account account: [
            Select Name
            From Account
            Where Name = :ac.Family_Account__c
                and Weekly_Tuition__c > 0
        ]) {Transaction__c nt = new Transaction__c(); 

           nt.Family_Account__c = at.Name;
           nt.Notes__c = 'Automated Charge';
           nt.Transaction_Date__c = System.Today();
           nt.Transaction_Type__c = 'Tuition Charge';
           nt.Amount__c = at.Weekly_Tuition__c * -1;

           trans_insert.add(nt);}
           //database.insert(nt);

        for(Account account: [
            Select Name
            From Account
            Where Name = :ac.Family_Account__c
                and Extra_Curricular_Tuition_Fee__c > 0
        ]) {Transaction__c ne = new Transaction__c();

           ne.Family_Account__c = ae.Name;
           ne.Notes__c = 'Automated Charge';
           ne.Transaction_Date__c = System.Today();
           ne.Transaction_Type__c = 'Tuition Charge';
           ne.Amount__c = ae.Extra_Curricular_Tuition_Fee__c * -1;

           trans_insert.add(ne);}

    insert trans_insert;
    }
}
```

**Here's the code I got working, finally!!!** For simplicity's sake, I divided the two transactions I was trying to write into two separate classes (easier to debug that way). Here's the class I have working so far.

```
global class scheduledWeekly implements Schedulable {
    //Variables of CRON_EXP in the order they appear
        //Seconds: 0-59 - No special characters allowed
        //Minutes: 0-59 - No special characters allowed
        //Hours: 0-23 - Special Characters: , - * /
        //Day of Month: 1-31 - Special Characters: , - * ? / L W
        //Month: 1-12 - Special Characters: , - * ? / L W
        //Day of Week: 1-7 - Special Characters: , - * ? / L #
        //Year (optional): null or 1970-2099
   //Special Character Descriptions
        //, delimits values
        //- specifies a range
        //* specifies all possible values
        //? no specific value
        //use a slash(/) to indicate a starting point followed by an increment
        //L is the Last
        //W is the closest Weekday
        //# specifies the nth day in the format of day_of_week by day of month
public static String CRON_EXP = '0 39 15 * * ? *';

global static String scheduleIt() {
scheduledWeekly sw = new scheduledWeekly();
return System.schedule('Weekly Billing', CRON_EXP, sw);
}

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    List <Transaction__c> trans_insert = new List <Transaction__c>();

    Account[] at = [
        Select Name
            , Weekly_Tuition__c
        From Account
        Where Id in (Select Family_Account__c 
                     From Child__c 
                     Where Enrolled__c = true)
            and Weekly_Tuition__c > 0
    ];

    system.debug('Manual Debug >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Active Accounts with Tuition:' + at);

    System.debug('Manual Debug >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ' + at.size() + ' records found with tuition charges needed.');
    if(at.size() > 0)
    {
        System.debug('Manual Debug >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> at.size found to be greater than 0.');
        for(Account account: [
        Select Name
            , Weekly_Tuition__c
        From Account
        Where Id in (Select Family_Account__c 
                     From Child__c 
                     Where Enrolled__c = true)
            and Weekly_Tuition__c > 0
    ]) {Transaction__c newTuitionCharge = new Transaction__c(); 
           newTuitionCharge.Family_Account__c = account.Id;
           newTuitionCharge.Notes__c = 'Automated Charge';
           newTuitionCharge.Transaction_Date__c = System.Today();
           newTuitionCharge.Transaction_Type__c = 'Tuition Charge';
           newTuitionCharge.Amount__c = account.Weekly_Tuition__c * -1;

           system.debug('Manual Debug >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Family_Account: ' + newTuitionCharge.Family_Account__c);
           system.debug('Manual Debug >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Tuition Amount: ' + newTuitionCharge.Amount__c);

           trans_insert.add(newTuitionCharge);
           system.debug('Manual Debug >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>newTuitionCharge added to trans_insert list.');}
    }

    system.debug('Manual Debug >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>' + trans_insert.size() + ' rows ready to be saved.');

    Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(trans_insert,false);
    for(Database.SaveResult sr : srList){
        if(sr.isSuccess()){
            system.debug('Successfully inserted Transaction. Transaction ID: ' + sr.getID());
        }
        else{
            for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()){
                System.debug('The following error has occurred.');
                System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                System.debug('Transaction fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());

            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain your code is executing? According to the documentation Salesforce CRON Expressions only want 6 parameters and you have 7. The 6 part CRON expression is documented here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm

Do you see a row for it at /a0e ("Scheduled Apex" in the setup side menu)? Does the "Next Scheduled Run" column and match your expectation? You can delete that row from the admin screen and then rerun `scheduledWeekly.scheduleIt()` to reschedule if necessary.

If the problem is in your code, you need to collect a debug log and parse through it for clues. You can add various `System.debug()` calls to get a better picture of what your code is doing when you parse through the log. What is the size of `trans_insert` for instance? Zero would be a big clue and I'd then ask what's the size of `ac`, `at`, and `ae`?

Also, change that last line to

```
Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(trans_insert);
```

Then you can comb log errors from the insert. In my experience, validation rules often bubble up unexpectedly during insert/update operations and you can get the necessary details from `Database.SaveResult[]` like so:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_saveresult

I do find it a little hard to find my debug lines buried in the other log noise so I've gotten in the habit of using a little text decoration to make it easy to find what interests me in the log:

```
System.debug('\n\n\n####### ' + something_interesting + ' ########\n\n\n');
```

Side note: I'm fairly certain you can capture the results of a real job execution by monitoring your user record at "Debug Logs" /setup/ui/listApexTraces.apexp but that can be annoying and time consuming. It is easier to setup a second method named `execute2()` and move your `execute(SchedulableContext sc)` code there. `execute()` calls `execute2()` obviously. The beauty is that you can run `scheduledWeekly.execute2();` on demand to easily capture a debug log.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, the CRON_EXP statement is rendering correctly in the Scheduled Jobs list. The documentation I found has seconds as the first number, while it's lacking on yours. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm. Curious. I'm going to give this a try right now!

Comment: Looks like the 7th param is optional_year so that's not it. Any luck with getting the debug logs?

Comment: Thank you for following up. I've been running into one error after another, but have been able to resolve them with a little research. I couldn't have done all this without the use of the debug logs, so thank you! I finally got it working!!! I'll post an update with the working code. Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW the most experienced Salesforce folks are answering questions over at salesforce.stackexchange.com now so you might want to ask your next question there.

Comment: Thank you! I saw that after I had already posted my question. You really helped me out a lot. You led me to the water and made me drink. I learned a lot!